# C++で文字列を2進数変換して出力する方法

Tags: c++

C++で、文字列を2進数表記のintに変換する方法を探しています。
いろいろと検索しては見ましたが、どれもprintfを用いた標準出力の方法でした。

文字列をバイナリ変換し、それを2進数変換、
結果を文字列変換し、数値に変換する
という手順を踏む必要があるのかなと思いますが、
stringなどのクラスにgetByte()などの関数も見当たらないため、どういった方法で変換するのかわかりません。

たとえば、
"文字列"　という入力があった場合、
"e69687 e5ad97 e58897"
に変換し、
"[1110 0110 1001 0110 1000 0111] [1110 0101 1010 1101 1001 0111] [1110 0101 1000 1000 1001 0111]"
となります。
これを
int[] mo = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...]
int[] zi = [1, 1,  1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...]
略
という形に変換したいです。

Comment: `"a"` -->  `111101` のようなことですか？具体的な変換例を挙げて貰えますか？ 「2進数表記のint」とは、例えば１０を１０１０（千十）とするというような意味でしょうか？

Comment: 「printfを用いた標準出力の方法」 具体的にどのような方法で、それがだめな理由を説明して下さい。
文字列からそれぞれの文字は`str[index]`のようにしてまたはイテレータを使って一文字ずつ取り出せます。

Comment: `char a = 'a'; int i = (int)a; `とか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 の wstring_convert class と range-based for loop を使ってみました。配列ではなく vector に変換結果を格納しています。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt> 
#include <climits>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  const u32string str = U"SO新年";
  vector<int>** bit_vectors = new vector<int>*[str.size()];
  wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> converter;

  int n = 0;
  for(const char32_t& c : str) {
    string u8_char = converter.to_bytes(c);
    bit_vectors[n] = new vector<int>(0);
    for(const char& uc : u8_char) {
      for(char& bc : bitset<CHAR_BIT>(uc).to_string()) {
        bit_vectors[n]->push_back(bc - '0');
      }
    }
    n++;
  }

  // Show all elements
  for(size_t i=0;i<str.size();i++){
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(2) << converter.to_bytes(str.at(i)) << ": ";
    cout << "[";
    for(const int &v : *bit_vectors[i]){
      cout << v << ", ";
    }
    cout << "\b\b]" << endl;
    delete bit_vectors[i];
  }
  delete bit_vectors;

  return 0;
}
```

**実行結果**

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~15.10) 5.2.1 20151028
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O -o bit_vectors bit_vectors.cc
$ ./bit_vectors
 S: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
 O: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
新: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
年: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```